# empty list as default value: same allocation in memory

Tags: python, list, empty-list

I want to initialize several instances of the same class with an initial empty list attribute, in which I want to add elements later in the script.

But I met a problem: the empty lists had the same allocation in memory.

For example, if I create this class with two instances:

```py
class FirstClass: 
    def __init__(self, values=[]):
        self.values = values

a = FirstClass()
b = FirstClass()
```

If I want to add a value in `b.values`:

```py
b.values += ['boat']
print(a.values) # ['boat']

# Also :

print(a.values is b.values) # True
```

It turns out that this solves my problem:

```py
class SecondClass:
    def __init__(self, values=None):
        self.values = values if values is not None else []

A = SecondClass()
B = SecondClass()

print(A.values is B.values) # False
```

I don't understand the difference at all, I consider myself lucky to have found this...

Is there a reason for the `FirstClass` not behaving like the `SecondClass` ?

Comment: Your class `FirstClass` suffers from the `"Mutable Default Argument"`. Your class `SecondClass` uses one of the solutions to this problem.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202311/say_it_again_values_not_expressions.html

Comment: default arguments re-use the same object